# How to add dynamic progress bars in each file downloaded using Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to develop a program using Primefaces that downloads all the images in a given URL. I've already successfully downloaded and it works fine but i need to add a functionality wherein i need to see the progress of all files being downloaded. Each file must have it's own progress bar. Also, one of the problems is having to create dynamic progress bars based on the files downloaded.

This is what i've come up so far.

@ManagedBean
public class CheckValidUrl {

```
    private static final String FOLDERPATH = "C:/Users/jan.louise.h.casas/Downloads/";
    private static final String IMAGE_PATTERN = "([^\\s]+(\\.(?i)(jpg|png|jpeg|ico|bmp))$)";

    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private String url;       
    private Integer progress;
    private static boolean progressBarRendered;     

    private List<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public List<String> getImagesList() {
        return imagesList;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Integer getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(Integer progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
    }

    public boolean isProgressBarRendered() {
        return progressBarRendered;
    }

    public void cancel(){
        progress = null;
    }

    public void onComplete() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Progress Completed"));
    }


    public void validateUrl() throws IOException {
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator();
        if(!urlValidator.isValid(url)){
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error!", "Please make sure URL is valid"));
        } else{
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info", "Please wait"));
            downloadImages();
        }
    }

    public void downloadImages(){

        try{
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");     
            if(img.size() > 0){
                for (Element el : img) {
                    String src = el.absUrl("src");
                    System.out.println("Image Found!");
                    System.out.println("src attribute is : "+src);
                    pattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);
                    if(validateImageType(src)){                     
                        imagesList.add(src);
                    }       
                }
                if(!imagesList.isEmpty()){
                    getImages(imagesList);
                } else{
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warning", "URL only has GIFs"));
                }

            } else{
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Warning", "URL doesn't have any images"));
            }

        } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
            System.err.println("There was an error");
            Logger.getLogger(CheckValidUrl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println("There was an error");
            Logger.getLogger(CheckValidUrl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static void getImages(List<String> imageSources) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {      

        for(String src : imageSources){

            int indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");

            if (indexname == src.length()) {
                src = src.substring(1, indexname);
            }

            indexname = src.lastIndexOf("/");
            String name = src.substring(indexname, src.length());

            System.out.println(name);
            URL url = new URL(src);

            InputStream in = url.openStream();
            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream( FOLDERPATH+ name));

            for (int b; (b = in.read()) != -1;) {
                progressBarRendered = true;
                out.write(b);
                System.out.println("Downloaded image: "+src);
                System.out.println("Boolean Value: "+progressBarRendered);
            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
        }
    }

    public boolean validateImageType(String image){
        pattern = Pattern.compile(IMAGE_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(image);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

}

and in my **check_valid_url.xhtml**

```
            <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

            <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5">

                <p:outputLabel for="url" value="Url:" />
                <p:inputText id="url" value="#{checkValidUrl.url}" required="true" label="Url" />
                <p:message for="url" display="icon" />                          


                <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="progressBarPanel" actionListener="#{checkValidUrl.validateUrl}" onclick="PF('pbAjax').start()" icon="ui-icon-check" />

            </h:panelGrid>    

            <h:panelGrid id="progressBarPanel">
                <p:progressBar widgetVar="pbAjax" ajax="true" rendered="#{checkValidUr.progressBarRendered}" value="#{checkValidUrl.progress}" labelTemplate="{value}%" styleClass="animated" global="false">
                    <p:ajax event="complete" listener="#{checkValidUrl.onComplete}" update="panel"/>
                </p:progressBar>     
            </h:panelGrid> 
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. We can assist with problems but not write your code for you.

Comment: sorry for that, i've edited with what i've come up so far